# FreeBSD script - different result to manual execution (tcsh)

Tags: freebsd, shell-scripting, unix-shell

This question has been asked previously in https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/securing-a-joomla-installation-on-apache-mod-php but it may belong here better since it is not Joomla specific.

I'm trying to execute a script in tcsh, and receive different results from running the commands individually on the command line to executing the script.
The attempt is to secure all directories below public_html; and assign more open permissions to some directories afterwards (e.g. cache, logs etc).

```
find ./public_html -type f ! -user apache -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find ./public_html -type d ! -user apache -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod -R 777 public_html/cache/
chmod -R 777 public_html/administrator/cache/
chmod -R 777 public_html/logs/
chmod -R 777 public_html/tmp/
```

In the above, quite often I find all permissions restricted but e.g. the cache, log or tmp directories unwritable after running the script. If I execute all commands one after another on the command line it works as expected. It'd be great if you might have an idea what I should be looking at instead?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, no answers - I'm still not sure why it doesn't work this way, but I've now found that `find ...directory` also includes the directory itself. So I've now changed the chmod commands to

```
find public_html/cache/ public_html/administrator/cache/ public_html/logs/  -type f ! -user apache -exec chmod 666{} \;
find public_html/cache/ public_html/administrator/cache/ public_html/logs/ -type d ! -user apache -exec chmod 777{} \;
```

That works for me. I recon that during shell execution in a row, it errors out once it encounters a file/directory where the script does not have rights to chmod.